# C - why does fread() have two possible behaviours if EOF is reached?

Tags: c

I can't understand why function fread() behaves differently in these 2 examples:

1)
I have a structure with a short and a char (size is 4 bytes including padding) and an array of three such structures.If I write each short and char of each structure separately with fwrite() and then read that file with fread() to a variable whose type is that structure, I will read 4 bytes at a time (there will be 9 bytes in the file) so you can see that one byte will be left in 3rd iteration (and one byte will be lost in each iteration).What happens is that there is no 3rd read because I'm left with one byte and fread has to read 4 bytes.

2)
A simpler example, if I write a 1 byte char to a file with fwrite() and then put the content of that file into a 4 byte int with fread(), the integer will get that data.

Why does this happen?Why does the data get read in one case but not in the other if EOF is reached?

Here is the first example:

```
int main()
{
    struct X { short int s; char c; } y, x[]=
    {{0x3132,'3'},{0x3435,'6'},{0x3738,'9'}};
    FILE *fp=fopen("FILE.DAT","wb+");
    if (fp)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[i]);)
        {
            fwrite(&x[i].s,sizeof(x[i].s),1,fp);
            fwrite(&x[i].c,sizeof(x[i].c),1,fp);
            i++;
        }
        rewind(fp);
        for(int i=0;fread(&y,sizeof(y),1,fp);)
        printf("%d:%x %c\n",++i, y.s, y.c);
        fclose(fp);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Second example:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp=fopen("FILE.DAT","wb+");
    char c = 'a';
    fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 1, fp);
    rewind(fp);

    int num;
    fread(&num, sizeof(num), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit to provide a [mcve]? Runnable code is a bit more concrete than text describing it.

Comment: @Acorn there isn't a file, a new one is written (wb+ is used because it can both write and read).

Comment: Which of your two examples is the code demonstrating - just the first, right? Do you have a question about the first example? Or is the question just why the second example, which I can't visualize and you haven't shown code for, is different?

Comment: You ask `fread` to read 1 item whose size is 4. a single item of size 4 does not exist (and clearly `fread` can't return a value like 0.5). What would you expect to happen? `fread` is allowed to read a smaller number of items (as in your second example), but reading part of an item isn't reasonable.

Comment: @Useless the first one (it says above).

Comment: `A simpler example, if I write a 1 byte char to a file with fwrite() and then put the content of that file into a 4 byte int with fread(), the integer will get that data.` can you show us the exact code of this experiment you made?

Comment: @Hasturkun I've edited the question, in both examples we need more data than a file has so there isn't a difference between them.

Comment: Your second example doesn't check the return value of `fread`, or initialize the int before calling it and check the value after. Are you sure it reads part of one integer?

Comment: "there is no 3rd read" How do you know? "the integer will get that data." How do you know?

Comment: In the first example you only write 3 bytes (sizeof(short) + sizeof(char)) i.e. no padding, the you read back 4 bytes (sizeof(struct X)).

Comment: @n.m. there is no 3rd read because nothing is printed out.The integer in the second program gets all the data from file because I've checked it.

Comment: Example 1: The third read returns zero as it should. It is indeterminate whether any memory has been changed. Example 2: The first and only read returns 0 as it should. It is indeterminate whether any memory has been changed. "I checked it" is something I don't see in the code so I have no idea how you checked it, but it seems you are checking two different things in the two examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the data get read in one case but not in the other if EOF is reached?

"What happens is that there is no 3rd read because I'm left with one byte and fread has to read 4 bytes." is a questionable  premise.

1st Code did read 3 times.  There are with no bytes left to read.

In both codes, the last read was a *partial* read with a `fread()` return value of 0.[@Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646188/c-why-does-fread-have-two-possible-behaviours-if-eof-is-reached/57646458#comment101743769_57646188)
(The first code did not print the result of the 3rd read.)

With `fread()`, a return value of 0 does not mean "end-of-file" was immediately encountered - nothing read.  Instead, 0 means an complete read did not occur due to :
  * "end-of-file" or partial read.
  * rare I/O error.

---

> Why does this happen?

In the 2nd code, results may differ due to **Indeterminate behavior**

> `fread()` ... If a partial element is read, its value is indeterminate<sup>1</sup>  C11dr §7.21.8.1 2

`fread(&num, sizeof(num), 1, fp)` result may *or may not* be as expected.

A more informative example

```
int main(void) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("FILE.DAT", "wb+");
  char c = 'a';
  printf("  %8X\n", c);
  fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 1, fp);
  rewind(fp);

  unsigned num = rand();
  printf("  %8X\n", num);
  size_t len = fread(&num, sizeof(num), 1, fp);
  printf("%zu %8X\n", len, num);
  len = fread(&num, sizeof(num), 1, fp);
  printf("%zu\n", len);
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
        61  as expected
  5851F42D  as expected - some random value
0 5851F461  Indeterminate!  (in this case, looks like the LSByte was replaced.)
0           as expected
```

Moral of the story: assess the return value of `fread()` before relying on what was read into the buffer.

---

<sup>1</sup>  *indeterminate value*
either an unspecified value or a trap representation

Comment: If there was a 3rd read in the first program, then why was no result printed?

Comment: @user3711671 The 3rd read returned 0 quitting the `for(int i=0;fread(&y,sizeof(y),1,fp);) { }` loop - preventing a 3rd call to `printf()`.  To be clear, data was read on the 3rd `fread()`, just less than `sizeof(y)` bytes.

Answer (score 4):

> ... when `EOF` is reached ...

`EOF` isn't "reached". Many `<stdio.h>` functions return `EOF` as a signal that something went wrong, giving no indication what that something is. If you want to know what went wrong after receiving the signal, test with `feof()` and/or `ferror()`.